# Why am I getting null instead of the @Inject-ed field?

Tags: java, dagger-2

In the code below, I expected to get a new `Soap` object (line `#07`), but I get `null`. What am I missing here?

```
01| public class ExampleUnitTest {
02|     @Test
03|     public void DaggerTest() throws Exception {
04|         MyComponent myComponent = DaggerMyComponent.create();
05|         IThing thing = myComponent.getThing();
06|         Impl impl = thing.getImpl();
07|         ISoap soap = impl.soap;
08|         Assert.assertNotNull(soap); // fails here: soap is null!
09|     }
10| }
11|
12| interface ISoap{}
13| class Soap implements ISoap{}
14|
15| class Impl{
16|     @Inject public ISoap soap;
17| }
18|
19| @Module
20| class MyModule {
21|     @Provides IThing getThing(){ return new Thing(); }
22|     @Provides ISoap getSoap() { return new Soap(); }
23| }
24|
25| @Component(modules = MyModule.class)
26| interface MyComponent {
27|     IThing getThing();
28|     ISoap getSoap();
29| }
30|
31| interface IThing{
32|     Impl getImpl();
33| }
34|
35| class Thing implements IThing{
36|     @Override public Impl getImpl() { return new Impl(); }
37| }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use dagger field injection (annotating fields with `@Inject`) you need to manually inject the object *after* you created it.

```
class Impl {
     @Inject public ISoap soap; // requires field injection
}

// will only work with something like this
Impl myImpl new Impl();
component.inject(myImpl); // inject fields
```

This is not what you are doing. You are creating your object yourself *in your module* and expect it to be initialized. *You* created the object and *you* did not initialize it.

If you use modules, you need to return your *initialized* object.

```
// to create your thing, you need a soap. REQUIRE it in your parameters,
// then create your _initialized_ object (you could also use a setter)
@Provides IThing getThing(ISoap soap) { return new Thing(soap); }
```

Then you can use

```
IThing thing = myComponent.getThing();
```

and it will have a soap.

---

Also I do not know what you are trying to do by returning a new object from a getter.

```
class Thing implements IThing{
    @Override public Impl getImpl() { return new Impl(); }
}
```

If you call `new` yourself, again, you're trying to do daggers job.

---

You should have a good look at **constructor injection**. You could then just remove the module as a whole, it does not add any features to your example.

There are quite a lot of good and detailed tutorials, e.g. my blog post about [dagger basics](http://blog.davidmedenjak.com/android/2016/05/04/dagger-2-introduction.html) which should give a good introduction to dagger.

Comment: Is the `component.inject(myImpl)` method supposed to be created by me?

Comment: @Tar to use field injection, yes. Dagger does not just magically initialize your fields, you will have to use it. But again, you should have a good look on some more tutorials. If you just use field infection everywhere you are not making full use of dagger

Comment: I've been using `IoC`s for a long while, not in `Java` though, but `Dagger 2` seems to confuse me, maybe because of it being a compile-time... I mean, isn't it the `IoC`'s responsibility to create the dependencies graph? so what's the use of field injection? how does it help?

Comment: @Tar Dagger as a whole cannot be explained in a few lines, which is why I keep urging you to read some more tutorials, as things should become clearer then. Field injection should be used with classes where you can not modify the constructor or need an empty constructor. This is why you need the extra call to inject your fields

Comment: I am reading tutorials the past few days. Reading yours right now. One more question if I may... I've seen this: `@ActivityScope @Subcomponent(modules = {TestActivityModule.class}) public interface TestActivityComponent { void inject(TestActivity activity); }` (sorry for the one liner... it's a comment...), and no implementation of the `inject` method in user code (only in the `Dagger-2`'s code). Is the `inject` method automatically implemented because of its name (i.e. is the `inject` name automatically recognized) or because of the `@Subcomponent` part? (or some other reason?)

Comment: @Tar Dagger is compile time code generation -> Dagger will implement the `inject` method, this is why you use `DaggerSomeComponent` and not `SomeComponent`, everything prefixed with `Dagger**` is generated code

Comment: Ok, I got confused with that specific little sting - the injection part... when does it happen, what makes it happen and so on... also the name, that was in every example `inject(...)` made me wonder if it has to be named that way... finally got it, silly me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37160482/587467